# Problem with Grails 'war' command which is trying to read the config file

Tags: grails

I store the configuration for my Grails application (such as DB configuration) in an XML config file. My `DataSource.groovy` is using the config file to get the Database information.
Unfortunately, when I'm building the War file for my test environment (using command such as `grails test war stb09.war`), it is running my `DataSource.groovy`, trying to open the file which is not there in my development environment.

How can I postpone the opening of the file only when I deploy the war file, not in the war building process?

Thank you,
Robert

Comment: FYI, we are using Grails 1.2.0

Answer (score 2):

I am supposing you do something like this in your `DataSource.groovy` file:

```
def db = new groovy.util.XmlParser().parse("connection.xml")
```

Easy and dirty workaround, is to put a try catch around it like this:

```
try {
  def db = new groovy.util.XmlParser().parse("connection.xml")
} catch (Exception e ) {println "Bad timing"}
```

In my projects, I am actually using something like this:

```
environments {
  production {
        grails.config.locations <<  "classpath:${appName}-db-custom.properties"
}}
```

This way, no problem at packaging time, and at run time you can replace your datasource with approriate values.

Time-wise, grails is loading the connection data from a compiled `DataResource.groovy` first, and then put those in the global configuration. Those values are then dynamically overwritten at run-time by the configuration in the property file.